# How to add App Analytic to Login event using Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, events, analytics, facebook-sdk-4.x

I want to add App Analytic for following event using Facebook SDK.

```
Login
In-App Purchase
```

I had read out the documentation at developers.facebook.com. But I am getting confused that I have to create my own analytic method for above event or there is specific method for above event.

If anyone have idea then suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For In App Purchase just enable this option inside application/Setting
>   in https://developers.facebook.com

[image]

> For Login Event you can make custom event like

```
[FBSDKAppEvents logEvent:@"Login"
                  parameters:@{
      @"User ID"    : @"You User ID",
      @"User Name" :  @"You User Name"
                                } ];
```